# Approximate largest rectangle inside convex polygon

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, contour

In my project I am using python with opencv. I have an contour of a random polygon and need an approximation of largest rectangle to fit the inside. I found some article describing how to find the optimal solution, but that require a lot of coding and is quite demanding.

Are there some easier way to **approximate the largest rectangle** inside an concave polygon? Precision does not have to be that high.

Comment: check https://pypi.org/project/maxrect/   please, it should help

Comment: Aslo may be useful:  https://github.com/pogam/ExtractRect